# How to I extract the autocomplete email addresses stored in Outlook for general use?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, csv, address-book

Many people at my org don't use Outlook's contacts features, so they have none to export.
Instead they rely on the autocomplete list.
I'm *not* asking about how to [transfer this list as-is](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/import-or-copy-the-autocomplete-list-to-another-computer-83558574-20dc-4c94-a531-25a42ec8e8f0), e.g. when getting a new workstation.
Sometimes we need these lists in a textual format.
There are no `.nk2` files because the accounts use IMAP, so Outlook stores the data internally (as described at the linked help).
Is there an easy way to obtain them?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I have the most efficient solution, but it did work.
I have a Linux workstation, so I tore the text out, kicking and screaming, using tools I already know.
You might be able to do the same with the Windows versions and/or the BASH shell that comes with [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/), if you don't have other suitable programs to process the files.

1. Use MFCMAPI on the source machine to extract the `IPM.Configuration.Autocomplete` file as a TXT file.
   Out of scope but you can follow the first part of the transfer instructions linked in the question.
2. Open the file in a text editor, it's XML.
   Go to the `<property>` that contains `PR_ROAMING_BINARYSTREAM`, and save only the long hexadecimal string (`0DF0...`) in the `<Value>` as separate plain text file, e.g. `automplete-dump-hex.txt`.
   Save it in ASCII/UTF-8, without a byte-order mark.
3. Convert this file containing the hex stream to binary. I used a command like this:

   ```sh
   xxd -r -p < automplete-dump-hex.txt > automplete-dump-raw.txt
   ```
4. This raw text contains plain text parts, in UTF-16, little-endian, but it also has binary data and the strings are separated with null bytes.
   You can open this in any suitable editor and go your own way, from here.
   I opened it in Vim, forcing the encoding `:e ++enc=utf-16le automplete-dump-raw.txt`, then overwrote it as UTF-8 (`:set fileencoding=utf-8`).
5. I treated the nulls as line separators and searched for any containing an `@`, then converted the nulls to newlines:

   ```sh
   grep -zF @ automplete-dump-raw.txt | tr '\000' '\n' > automplete-dump-possibles.txt
   ```
6. Then I tidied up the last output file into a friendlier format (TSV):

   1. Sorted and removed duplicate lines (Vim `:sort u`);
   2. Deleted lines of bogus data;
   3. Used regex replace to convert `name <email@address>` to two separate fields;
   4. Removed single-quotes surrounding some names; and
   5. De-duplicated again, preferring lines with name + address over just address.

This successfully produced lists with hundreds of unique addresses, which I was happy with.
I think this description of the steps is longer than the actual steps.